# Processing 3.3.7 draw() stops looping

Tags: processing, draw

I wrote this code on Processing 3.3.7, it creates a ball that bounces around.

```
Ball b;

int n = 0;

void setup() {
  size(600, 400);

  b = new BallBuilder()
          .buildRadius(20)
          .buildXSpeed(5)
          .buildYSpeed(5)
          .buildYAcceleration(1)
          .toBall();
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  n++;
  print("n: " + n + " | ");
  print("xSpeed: " + b.getXSpeed() + " | ");
  println("ySpeed: " + b.getYSpeed());

  b.display();
  b.move();
}
```

There is also a Ball class, which has these methods:

```
  void display() {
    fill(255);
    stroke(255);
    ellipse(xPosition, yPosition, radius * 2, radius * 2);
  }

  void move() {
    this.moveX();
    this.moveY();
  }

  private void moveX() {
    for(float i = 0; i <= abs(this.xSpeed); i += abs(this.xSpeed) / 10) {
      this.bounceX();
      this.xPosition += this.xSpeed / 10;
    }
  }

  private void moveY() {
    for(float i = 0; i <= abs(this.ySpeed); i += abs(this.ySpeed) / 10) {
      this.bounceY();
      this.yPosition += this.ySpeed / 10;
    }

    this.ySpeed += this.yAcceleration;
  }

  void bounceX() {
    if(!this.canMoveX()) {
      this.xSpeed = -this.xSpeed;
    }
  }

  void bounceY() {
    if(!this.canMoveY()) {
      this.ySpeed = -this.ySpeed;
    }
  }

  boolean canMoveX() {
    if(this.xPosition < radius || this.xPosition >= width - this.radius) {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

  boolean canMoveY() {
    if(this.yPosition < radius || this.yPosition >= height - this.radius) {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

And there's also a builder and two getters for the Ball(not posted here, as they're pretty straight forward). The problem is, neither the xSpeed nor the ySpeed can be set to 0, otherwise the code stops running. That means that I need to give it both speeds when instantiating and if I set the acceleration makes the speed go to 0, the program stops running (the `n` variable is used to count the number of times the draw() loops, when the speed hits 0, it stops increasing). What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [debugging your code](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) to figure out where the code differs from what you expected?

You have two loops like this:

```
for(float i = 0; i <= abs(this.xSpeed); i += abs(this.xSpeed) / 10) {
```

You might add a print statement inside these loops, like this:

```
println("i: " + i);
```

If you did this, you'd discover that `i` is always `0`. Why is that?

Think about what happens if `this.xSpeed` is `0`: when will this loop exit?

Comment: Thanks, the problem was the `>=` which should actually be a `>`, otherwise, the loop never exits, as you pointed out.